# How do I save user data in a file and populate the GUI/Software based on that file?

Tags: design, python, software, gui-design

So I'm developing a GUI that consists of many widgets such as checkbox, buttons, radio-buttons, combo-box using **Python Qt5**.
This GUI is to perform some calcualtion based on user choices.
I'm trying to figure out how to go about **saving** all this data in a file and then **repopulating** those widgets when the user opens the **same** file.

My research lead me to [QSetting](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html?highlight=qsetting#more) class of Qt5 but that only saves the states of widgets.

For Example:

```
    def writeSettings(self):
    self.settings = QSettings("Moose Soft", "Clipper")
    self.settings.beginGroup("MainWindow")
    self.settings.setValue("size", self.size())
    self.settings.setValue("pos", self.pos())
    self.settings.endGroup()

def readSettings(self):
    self.settings = QSettings("Moose Soft", "Clipper")
    self.settings.beginGroup("MainWindow")
    self.resize(settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400)).toSize())
    self.move(settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint())
    self.settings.endGroup()
```

But this is not doing what I want (or maybe I'm not aware of some of its functionalities?)

Summary: What I want is to have the user save the file and come back to that file after a while and the file should know which widgets was checked/used and repopulate only those.
How do I approach this issue?

By the way, I'm new to GUI design :-/

Comment: I don't do python, but in all the other languages I've used (programming since 80s)  working with flat files/ini files/etc can be a pain unless there is a good/great wrapper library/class.  I'd look at using a small db like SQLite.

Comment: Are you aware of the Model-View-Controller pattern?    That's an extremely important design pattern to know if you're doing anything with GUIs - I'd recommend  taking the time to look into it, since the concepts of GUI design versus data persistence (e.g. file I/O) are entirely separate concerns, and it's generally recommended that you keep code related to those things completely separate from each other.      Data persistence is a problem which is better solved completely independently without using anything from your GUI framework.

Comment: Thank you **@Ivan** & **@Ben**!  
I was trying to avoid implementing SQL in the GUI but I have to look into it.
**Ben** I briefly looked into it right now. Looks like I need to get deeply familiar with this software  architectural pattern.  
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An effective technique ive used is to create a dict where the keys are the gui elements and their parameters, and the values are the arguments the user put in those parameters.

Example

```
data = {
    frame1:{textBox1:"input text", textBox2:"input text"}, 
    frame2:{Button1: 0, Button2: 1},}
```

If you want to get really slick you can rename the gui elements with the actual data you are collecting

Comment: This answer doesn't talk about saving and reloading, which seem pretty key to the OP's question.